# Independence and dependence in the set $S$ = {$cv_1, v_1 + v_2$}

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and assume that {$v_1, v_2$} is a basis of $V$. Consider the set $S$ = {$cv_1, v_1 + v_2$}, where $c \in {\bf R}$. I believe each of the following statements is true, but would like to see if I am right:

(1) $S$ is linearly dependent only when $ c = 0$.

(2) So the set $S$ is linearly independent for all nonzero $c$.

(3) $S$ is a basis of $V$ for all nonzero $c$.

(4) All the values of $c$ for which $S$ spans $V$ are the nonzero $c$'s.

Comment: For 1), it is linear dependent if you assume zero as an element of the set. I think that is what you mean.

Comment: right. If $c = 0$ then $S$ becomes {$0, v_1 + v_2$} which is dependent (any set containing zero is dependent). But are there any other values of $c$ that make this true? I didn't think so.

Comment: I don't think so either. If the set is independent, then adding one member to another gives another independent set

Answer (score 0):

For (1) let's say that the set $S$ is linearly dependent then:
$$\exists \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R} \text{ with } \alpha \neq 0 \text{ or } \beta \neq 0\text{: } \alpha cv_{1} + \beta(v_{1}+v_{2}) = 0$$
$$ (\alpha c+\beta)v_{1} + \beta v_{2} = 0 \Rightarrow \beta = 0 \land \alpha c = -\beta$$
Because we assumed that $\alpha$ or $\beta$ was different from zero, we conclude that $c=0$.

Then (2) follows.

For (3) we have that the dimension of $V$ is two. Then if the set $S$ is linearly independent ($c\neq 0$) it must span $V$.

For (4) if the set $S$ is linearly dependent the subspace generated by it has dimension less than two, then it doesn't span $V$.